# Using stringr in R - number string

Tags: r, stringr

I want to subset a data table (`DS`) based on a column (`Col`) with the format `"00000000000000123456"` using regular expressions in R.

Numbers that meet this format should be output to `DS_Correct` and those that do not match should be output to `DS_Error`.

I tried using the stringr functions:

```
DS_Correct <- if(str_match (DS$Col,"/^[1-9][:digits:]{0,12}$/)) > 0
DS_Error <- if(str_match (DS$Col,"/^[1-9][:digits:]{0,12}$/)) > 0
```

But i get the error:

> Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
>   ""/^[1-9]\d"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please consider to review your question according to SO guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and whether possible, share an extract of your data. Which is the format you're looking for? a string with 12 zeros followed by 8 numbers or what?

Comment: I don't understand the pattern you want, is it 14 zeros followed by 6 digits? Also, your `if` statements do not make sense.